# How to typedef a generic function?

Tags: dart, dart-2

I have a generic static method that looks like this:

```
static build<K>() {
    return (GenericClass<K> param) => MyClass<K>(param);
}
```

So far I have tried:

```
typedef F = MyClass<K> Function(GenericClass<K> param);
```

but it says that:

> `The return type '(GenericClass<K>) → MyClass<K>' isn't a '(GenericClass<dynamic>) → MyClass<dynamic>', as defined by the method 'build'.`

and

```
typedef F = SimpleViewModel<K> Function<k>(Store<K> param);
```

Which says that:

> `The return type '(GenericClass<K>) → MyClass<K>' isn't a '<K>(GenericClass<K>) → MyClass<K>', as defined by the method 'build'.`

`MyClass` looks like this:

```
class MyClass<T> {
  final GenericClass<T> param;

  MyClass(this.param);


  static build<K>() {
      return (GenericClass<K> param) => MyClass<K>(param);
  }
}
```

So, what is a valid `typedef` for it?

Comment: I might sound stupid but this did it `typedef F<I> = MyClass<I> Function(GenericClass<I> param);` and `static F<K> build<K>() {...}`, makes sense to me, but I can't still explain why, though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two concepts of "generic" when it comes to a typedef. The typedef can be generic on a type, or the typedef can refer to a generic function (or both):

A typedef which is generic on `T`:

```
typedef F<T> = T Function(T);
```

Then in usage:

```
F first = (dynamic arg) => arg; // F means F<dynamic>
F<String> second = (String arg) => arg; // F<String> means both T must be String
```

A typedef which refers to a generic function on `M`:

```
typedef F = M Function<M>(M);
```

Then in usage:

```
F first = <M>(M arg) => arg; // The anonymous function is defined as generic
// F<String> -> Illegal, F has no generic argument
// F second = (String arg) => arg -> Illegal, the anonymous function is not generic
```

Or both:

```
typedef F<T> = M Function<M>(T,M);
```

And in usage:

```
F first = <M>(dynamic arg1, M arg2) => arg2; // F means F<dynamic> so the T must be dynamic
F<String second = <M>(String arg1, M arg2) => arg2; // The T must be String, the function must still be generic on the second arg and return type
```

Comment: Can you explain why this doesn't work ? ```typedef F<T> = M Function<M>(T);

F<String> first = <int>(String arg){
  return arg.length;
};```

Comment: It looks like you probably want `typedef F<T, M> = M Function(T); F<String, int> first = (arg) { return arg.length; };`. In your example you have both types of generics, the tyepdef is generic, and it refers to a generic function. Your concrete function is not generic, it can _only_ return an `int`, it can't be specialized during usage to return a different type.

Comment: yes indeed, thank you. The error message is somewhat unclear :-) "The return type 'int' isn't a 'int', as defined by anonymous closure "